# xorg requires gtk 3

Tags: xorg, gtk

I want to install xorg on my minimal Ubuntu server to play with XLib.

```
sudo apt install xorg
```

However for some reason xorg package depends on gtk 3:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
```

How can I install X11 without installing GTK?

Latest Ubuntu 18.10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I may suspect is dependency on `x-terminal-emulator` virtual package. Here:

- [Dependencies of `xorg`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/xorg)
- [Packages which are providing the virtual package `x-terminal-emulator`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/x-terminal-emulator)

APT may pick one of `gnome-terminal` or `xfce4-terminal`, both are built on GTK GUI kit.

I may able to avoid this by pre-selecting the other terminal `xterm`  which based on Xorg.

```
sudo apt install xterm xorg
```